# How to extract images from Access CommandButton?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access database that I am working on, and need to extract the images from a few CommandButtons on a Form and save the images as files.

I haven't been able to do this using VBA. Anyone done this before or know how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean "extract the images from a few CommandButtons "? Like, capture the image that is used on the actual buttons and save them elsewhere? Or do these buttons merely let the user pick an image file using a standard dialog?

Comment: I want to use the SavePicture command to save the Picture in the command button to a file. However I don't believe that that SavePicture command works with the CommandButton object. So I want to know if there is any innovative VBA technique that exists, that can be used to achieve this?

Comment: What type of picture is it? It has to have been added from disk, either a file in itself, or from an icon library, so perhaps you should be looking there? Here are some applications, I have not tried any of them: http://opensource.software.informer.com/download-opensource-icon-extractor/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used some of the Access built-in images, by using a simple graphics program to capture the screen image, then saving it to whatever format you require (eg bmp etc).